# How to make a pull request for a particular branch of a repository in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I have several branches and I want to pull a particular branch of that repository in Android Studio. How to get it done through Android Studio?

Comment: That functionality isn't implemented yet if I'm not mistaken, I would just open up the integrated terminal window and just pull the project from there.

Comment: Or you can use a Git GUI client like [link](https://www.gitkraken.com/) and from there you will see easily all the branches and pull which one you want.